# xargs' $1 conflicts with $1 in shell script

Tags: linux, shell, arguments, xargs

I have these lines in one shell script file foo.sh:

```
ps ax | grep -E "bar" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9 $1
```

when I execute the shell script with an arguments like this:

```
sh foo.sh arg_one
```

the xargs can't work now. It takes the $1 from the shell script but not the output of awk.

I do know I can store the output of awk into one file and use it in xargs later.

But, is there any better solution?

== edited ==

thanks the answer from @peterph.
But, is there any way that I can use $1 in xargs?

== edited 2 ==

thanks @Brian Campbell

Despite weather there should be a useless $1 in the example, if a argument of "the shell script file" is given, then the $1 in xargs will not work as my wish, in my computer(In your computer too, I think).
Why? And, how to get avoid it?

Comment: if you need filename placeholders in xargs, use the `-I` option -- e.g. `xargs -I X cp X X.bak` -- check the man page

Comment: @glennjackman
yes, u r right. I've already checked the manual and then gave out this question: What is the mechanism of shell(or unix) for this strange issue(or feature)?

Comment: The mechanism is [shell expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) that occur *before* the command is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xargs` reads list from `stdin` so just discard the last `$1` on the line if what you want is to kill processes by their PIDs.

As a side note, `ps` can also print processes according to their command name (with procps on linux see the `-C` option).

Comment: @dennisyuan No, but for your particular one-liner, you don't need it. You can just drop the $1, and it would kill all the PIDs that awk prints out.

Comment: @nos
yes, u r right. But why the $1 works when there is no argument from the shell script, but does not work when there is one argument?

Comment: @dennisyuan The $1 works in that case because $1 is empty, so you end up with actually running `xargs kill -9` , just as when you drop the $1

Comment: @nos
I considered about that. Seems the xargs can not "reuse" or "rewrite" the $1 since there is already a $1 which is not empty, right?
What is the mechanism of shell(or unix) for this strange issue(or feature)?

Comment: @dennisyuan The shell expands variables as far as it can. I'm not sure what you want xargs to do with $1 , xargs knows nothing about variables or what $1 is supposed to mean. (unlike awk, where $1 means something different than in a shell. Since your awk program is enclosed in single quotes, the shell will not expand variables within those quotes though)

Comment: @dennisyuan why would you want to use `$1` in the `xargs` part of the pipe anyway (in this particular case)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of that complicated pipeline, you can always use `killall -9 name` to kill a process, or `pkill -9 pattern` if you don't know the exact name of the process but know a substring (be careful that you don't kill any unintended processes, though).

For your command to work, just remove the `$1`; `xargs` takes its arguments from standard in, and runs the command line passing in the values it gets from standard in at the end of the command.

**edit** (in response to your edit): What do you expect `xargs` to do with the `$1` argument? What are you expecting to be in it? The only interpretation of `$1` that has any meaning here is the first argument that was passed to your script.

The `$1` from your `awk` script is what `awk` finds in the first column of its input; it then prints that out, and `xargs` takes those values from standard input, and will call the command you pass it with those values at the end of the command line. So if the `awk` command returns:

```
100
120
130
```

Then piping that result to `xargs kill -9` will result in the following being called:

```
kill -9 100 120 130
```

You do not need a variable like `$1` to make this work

Comment: probably there are a few processes that contain bar. On the other hand, I do not see why he added `-E` for extended regexps...

Comment: Also, be warned, some OSes (notably Solaris) have a `killall` that does something drastically different - i.e. it kills everything, regardless of any command line arguments. (I know this was tagged "linux", but still...).

Comment: @alinsoar `killall` and `pkill` will both kill all of the processes that match.

Comment: @twalberg Yeah, I figured `killall` was safe since he specified Linux. But your right, you should check which one you have before using it.

Comment: @ Brian : killall match whole name, not substrings, etc

Comment: @Brian Campbell
if you pass a arguments to the shell script file like I wrote above, the $1 in xargs will not work as your wish. I want to know why, and how to avoid it.

Comment: @alinsoar That's why I mentioned `pkill`, if you want to match against a substring of the name. `killall` will match the whole name (technically, just up to the first 15 characters), while `pkill` treats the name you pass as a regular expression, so it will match a substring (unless you use `^` and `$`). `pkill -9 bar` will kill `bar`, `foo-bar`, `bar-baz`, and so on.

Comment: @dennisyuan I do not understand what you are asking. You do not need the `$1`. `xargs` does not do anything to interpret `$1`. `$1` is just a shell variable in this case. If you want to pass the string `$1` to the `kill` command, you can quote it with single quotes (`'$1'`), but that wouldn't do anything special, it would just pass `$1` to the `kill` command, which probably wouldn't understand it. What are you expecting the `$1` to do?

Comment: @dennisyuan Try this. Run your command, but replace the `xargs` part with `xargs echo kill -9`. Then instead of running the command, you will see the command line that will be run. You will see that you don't need the `$1`; all of the PIDs will be passed into your command.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ps ax | grep -E "bar" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
result=$(ps -ef | grep -E "bar" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print $2}')
kill -9 $result
```

In my case piping xargs sometimes returned below error even if matched processes existed:

```
usage: kill [ -s signal | -p ] [ -a ] pid ...
       kill -l [ signal ]
usage: kill [ -s signal | -p ] [ -a ] pid ...
       kill -l [ signal ]
```